# Stop Gflot Auto injection of Jquery/javascript in GWT application

Tags: javascript, gwt

I need help with my GWT application. I'm trying to use Gflot with GWT but for some reason Im getting Javascript errors due to the Gflot conflicting with the inherit Javascript within my application. To stop this and control the javascript that is auto injected via Gflot, I followed this post:

https://code.google.com/p/gflot2/wiki/Usage

My implementation: -

```
**<inherits name="com.googlecode.gflot.GFlot" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.json.JSON" />

    <replace-with class="com.googlecode.gflot.client.resources.FlotJavaScriptLoader.NoInjectionImpl">
    <when-type-is class="com.googlecode.gflot.client.FlotJavaScriptLoader.Impl" />
     </replace-with>**
```

but for some reason, when I do this, I get a "no such class exists within com.googlecode.gflot.client.FlotJavaScriptLoader" Javascript error message. So I can't load any jacasvript files for GFLOT manually. Any help on this would be great.

Cheers

Hash

Comment: <replace-with class="com.googlecode.gflot.client.resources.FlotJavaScriptLoader.NoInjectionImpl">
<when-type-is class="com.googlecode.gflot.client.resources.FlotJavaScriptLoader.Impl" />
 </replace-with>**

Answer (score 0):

Try with `<set-property name="gflot.load" value="EXTERNAL" />` and remove the `replace-with`.

This documentation is outdated, the project has been merged with gflot and you can find more up to date documentation here : https://code.google.com/p/gflot/wiki/Usage or here : https://github.com/nmorel/gflot